# appcompat_v7 library missing in android sdk manager

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat, android-sdk-manager

I need to use the appcompat_v7 library but it does not exist in my sdk and the extras in the eclipse sdk manager has just 1 item : android support library - and I have installed it . Where are all the other items. I want to install them but there is no way. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Use `SDK Manager` to install support library.

Comment: You have to import the appcompat library in your workspace. Check this link https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html.
The appcompat library has resources.

Comment: The appcompat v7 library does not exist in my sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

Note that the "support library" (as opposed to the "support repository") is hidden by default in the SDK manager, as it has been deprecated.  You need to check the "show: obsolete" checkbox. And then it's available to download.

Comment: What is the package called? Is it "appcompat_v7" literally? Or some other name?